# Name server management when using AWS Route 53 and Wix

Tags: dns, wix

I am very new to DNS configurations and such. I am reading and picking things up as I go. I was looking for general guidance for the following scenario,

I've a domain purchased from a registrar (Namecheap), I am using AWS Route 53 for DNS management. I am trying to build a simple website in Wix and associate it with my domain.

In my set up currently, my registrar points to AWS Route 53 name servers and AWS Route 53 contains A-records, and CNAMEs to resolve the website. The A-record and CNAMEs are provided by Wix.

However the problem is that my name server (AWS Route 53) is bound to a Wix A-record ("pointing" in Wix terminology). And as the IP on the Wix end could change anytime, the site availability remains at the mercy of Wix along with the hassle of manually updating the A-record in case of such changes.

A recommended method (from Wix) is that you use Wix name servers. But as I am using AWS Route 53 for my DNS, this isn't an option for me. As (based on my minimal understanding) there cannot be two sets of name servers pointing to different records (AWS Route 53 and Wix in my case).

Is there any guidance on how I can use name server technique in the above mentioned scenario? Something of that sort that AWS name servers -> Wix name servers -> A-records/CNAME for the website.

Any help/guidance is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If you only intend on using the domain with Wix, I would simply let them manage the DNS by pointing your domain to their name servers. Is there a specific reason for you to use Route 53? To me it seems like Wix allows you to manage additional DNS records like you would expect.